# multiple attributes in different combinations

Tags: xml, xslt

I have searched for a (simple) solution to the following problem and didn't succeed (maybe the keywords were bad?). So maybe the XSLT gurus can help.

Take an XML-snippet like

```
<inline bold="1">bold text</inline>
<inline super="1">superscript text</inline>
<inline bold="1" super="1">both: bold and superscript</inline>
```

The XSL stylesheet may include these templates:

```
<xsl:template match="inline[@bold='1']">
  <b>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </b>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="inline[@super='1']">
  <sup>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </sup>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, what is the best way to achieve an output like

```
<b>bold text</b>
<sup>superscript text</sup>
<sup><b>both: bold and superscript</b></sup>
```

for the example above,  where the third line is the location of interest?

How to simply apply multiple attribute values and combinations of them? The example given is the most trivial form of having multiple attributes that all lead to different output while all the combinations of them are valid as well. Next step would be `<inline bold="1" underline="1" super="1">`. I hope there is a solution that doesn't need to address all possible combinations explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 you can use http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-next-match:

```
<xsl:template match="inline[@bold='1']">
  <b>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </b>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="inline[@super='1']" priority="5">
  <sup>
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </sup>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 1.0 you can use stylesheet modules and do apply-imports.

Comment: You should probably put a `priority` on the second one to be certain it will fire first for elements that have both attributes.